How do I override the auto category page with a custom post?
I have created custom posts for my category pages. How can I override the automatically generated category page so that it loads the custom post I created?
In my settings, the URLs of categories are example.com/category-name/
I created a post for this category that I want the URL to be example.com/category-name/
But my subcategories are customized within categories so I want that to be loaded as a category page: example/category-name/sub-category
I tried updating the correct page in the permalink manager plugin but it's not working.
